# Is there an indication of the vibrations a disk was subjected to?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

I received today a new disk (traditional, plate-based one). It was quite loosely moving in a box, surrounded by a feeble wall of bubble-wrap.

The disk is brand new and I do not have specific reasons to assume there was something wrong on the way but it made me think: **is there a way to check the vibrations (acceleration in general) a disk was subjected to while disconnected?**

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. That would require an accelerometer which was powered up and had somewhere to store the data while the drive was in transit.

The closest thing would be to run some diagnostics and extensive read/write tests on the drive before using it to store any data. Watch the read/write error count on the drive (e.g. with a SMART tool) and see if it is going up quickly. If it is it indicates the drive may be damaged.